# Number is adding to file but not appearing when I print it

Tags: python

This is my entire code block but I am just having trouble making the scores show after the game is played. The score is being added to the file correctly, but when I go to print the scores, the new score is not appearing, even though I have appended it. How can I fix my code to make it show up? I am new to coding so anything helps. I think this is an easily solvable error, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you!

```
#STAGE 1: Opening the files and grabbing data
users_path = "c:\\Users\\Anna Hamelin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\SourceCode\\Project2\\usernames.txt"
passwords_path = "c:\\Users\\Anna Hamelin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\SourceCode\\Project2\\passwords.txt"
scoreslist_path = "c:\\Users\\Anna Hamelin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\SourceCode\\Project2\\scores.txt"

#Define functions for future use
def get_file_contents(file_path):
    return [line.strip() for line in open(file_path)]

scoreslist = get_file_contents(scoreslist_path)

def add_file_contents(file_path, contents):
    with open(file_path, "a") as file:
        file.write(contents)

def login_user(new_account=False):
    usernameslist = get_file_contents(users_path)
    passwordslist = get_file_contents(passwords_path)

#Determine if user needs to create a new account:
    if new_account:
        response = 'y'
    else:
        response = input("-"*50 + "\nWelcome! Do you have an account (y/n)? ")
        print("-"*50)

    #If user has an account:
    if response == "y":
            goodlogin = False
            username = input("Please enter your username: ")
            password = input("Please enter your password: ")
            for id in range(len(usernameslist)):
                if username == usernameslist[id] and password == passwordslist[id]:
                    goodlogin = True

            if goodlogin:
                print(print_in_green + "Access granted!" + print_default)
                #Ask if user would like to view leaderboard
                leaderboard = input("Would you like to view the leaderboard (y/n)? ")

                #If thet want to see leaderboard:
                if leaderboard == "y":
                    print("-"*50 + "\n" + print_in_blue + "Here is the leaderboard!\n" + print_default + "-"*50)
                    for c in range(0, len(scoreslist)-1):
                        max = scoreslist[c]
                        index_of_max = c
                        for i in range (c+1, len(scoreslist)):
                            if (scoreslist[i] > max):
                                max = scoreslist[i]
                                index_of_max = i
                        aux = scoreslist[c]
                        scoreslist[c] = max
                        scoreslist[index_of_max] = aux
                        #print(scoreslist)
                    print(*scoreslist, sep = "\n")
                    print("-"*50)
                    #If they don't want to see scores:
                else:
                    print("OK!")
            #If they type the wrong username or password:                      
            else:
                print(print_in_red + "Incorrect Login credentials, please try again by restarting." + print_default)

#If user does not have account:
    else:
        goodlogin2 = False
        newusername = input("What is your new username? ")
        #Check to see if username already exists
        if newusername in usernameslist:
            print("This username is already taken. Please try another.")
        else:
            goodlogin2 = True
            print(print_in_green + "Ok, please continue!" + print_default)
        #Check to see if two passwords match
        newpassword = input("What is your new password? ")
        newpasswordagain = input("Please enter your new password again: ")
        if newpassword == newpasswordagain:
            print("Please follow the instructions to log in with your new credentials.")
            add_file_contents(users_path, '\n' + newusername)
            add_file_contents(passwords_path, '\n' + newpassword)
            login_user(new_account=True)
        else:
            print(print_in_red + "Your passwords do not match. Please try again." + print_default)
login_user()

#Playing the game (rolling dice):
import random
min = 1
max = 6
sum = 0
#Ask user if they want to play
game_response = input("Would you like to play the game by rolling your dice (y/n)? ")

if game_response == "y":
    roll_again = "yes"

    while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
        print("Rolling the dices...")
        print("The values are:")
        dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
        dice2 = random.randint(min, max)
        print(print_in_pink)
        print(int(dice1))
        print(int(dice2))
        print(print_default)
        score = (int(dice1) + int(dice2))
        sum = sum + score
        roll_again = input("Your score for this round is " + str(score) + ". Roll the dices again (y/n)? ")
else:
    print("Ok!")

print("Your final score is " + print_in_pink + str(sum) + print_default + "!")
add_file_contents(scoreslist_path, '\n' + str(sum))
scoreslist.append(str(sum))

leaderboard_again = input("Would you like to view the leaderboard again (y/n)? ")
if leaderboard_again == "y":
    print("-"*50 + "\n" + print_in_blue + "Here is the leaderboard!\n" + print_default + "-"*50)
    for c in range(0, len(scoreslist)-1):
        max = scoreslist[c]
        index_of_max = c
        for i in range (c+1, len(scoreslist)):
            if (scoreslist[i] > max):
                max = scoreslist[i]
                index_of_max = i
        aux = scoreslist[c]
        scoreslist[c] = max
        scoreslist[index_of_max] = aux
    #print(scoreslist)
    print(*scoreslist, sep = "\n")
    print("-"*50)
    #If they don't want to see scores:
else:
    print("OK. Thanks for logging in!")
```

Comment: Is `sum` in `scoreslist`?  Is your assignment asking you to implement your own sort here?  If so, you should be factoring the sorting out into its own function. Otherwise, you should be using the built-in `list.sort`.  Could you provide some sample values of the variables this code doesn't define, so that we can have a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I updated it with all of my code so hopefully it's more clear now. Did that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update `scoreslist` to have `sum` in it (either by `append`ing it or by reading `scoreslist` out of the file again).  Add a line that adds `sum` to `scoreslist`:

```
add_file_contents(scoreslist_path, '\n' + str(sum))
scoresline.append(sum)
```

Comment: That worked but now I have the error "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'" in line 148. How can I fix that?

Comment: You would append `str(sum)` instead of `sum`.  Note that when you sort strings, they're sorted lexicographically, so `2 > 10`. It would make more sense to have everything in `scoreslist` be an integer by changing `get_file_contents` to `[int(line.strip()) for line in open(file_path)]`.  There may be other changes you would need to support that though.

Comment: I made some changes and updated my code but the new score still isn't appearing when I print the leaderboard after the game. Any ideas?